# Upload .msg file to Exchange Server using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, msg

I have found several examples of downloading an email message from a MS Exchange server and saving it to a file.

I need the opposite. From a ".msg" file I need to create an email message inside a specific folder of the server.

I found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/uploaditems-operation) on how to do it using an EWS request with a XML body. However, all my system relies on [EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633710(v%3Dexchg.80)), and I couldn't find an equivalent method to perform this operation.

How could I perform the operation I need? Could I pass a custom request through a [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api) Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft documentation link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange).

> You can use the **UploadItems** EWS operation to upload an item as a data stream. This data stream representation of an item **has to come from the results of an ExportItems operation call**. Because the EWS Managed API does not implement the UploadItems operation, if you use the EWS Managed API, you'll need to write a routine to send the web requests.

You may be able to convert your .msg file to an .eml and use the following code to add your message.

```
private static void UploadMIMEEmail(ExchangeService service)
{
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);

    string emlFileName = @"C:\import\email.eml";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(emlFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        int numBytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            int n = fs.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            if (n == 0)
                break;
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        }
        // Set the contents of the .eml file to the MimeContent property.
        email.MimeContent = new MimeContent("UTF-8", bytes);
    }

    // Indicate that this email is not a draft. Otherwise, the email will appear as a 
    // draft to clients.
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
    email.SetExtendedProperty(PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read, 1);
    // This results in a CreateItem call to EWS. The email will be saved in the Inbox folder.
    email.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
}
```